# Am I passing and accessing vector by reference correctly?

Tags: c++, sfml

Hello I'm still quite new to C++ and more so SFML. I am wondering if I may have a pass by value/reference miss match in this example specific to vectors maybe.
The below does not seem to work, I have no idea why.

Apologies if a trivial example, base on what's here. id rather not paste any additional functionality of the project code as it may make my query all the more difficult to understand.

----- class scope globals, previously all initialized in class constructor, without problem

```
string t1Path, t2Path, t3Path, t4Path, t5Path;
vector<string> texturePaths = {t1Path, t2Path, t3Path, t4Path, t5Path};
sf::Texture t1, t2, t3, t4, t5;
vector<sf::Texture> textures = {t1, t2, t3, t4, t5};
```

// the updation does not work

```
void updateTexturePaths(vector<string>& tPathsRef) {    
   // or this ?   texturePaths = tPathsRef;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < textures.size(); i++) {
      texturePaths[i] = tPathsRef[i];
   }
}

playerPtr->updateTexturePaths(playerPtr->idlingRSpritePaths);
```

but if I do this externally of the fuction, and not use/call the function it works, am I not understanding something, based only on the code here?

```
playerPtr->t1Path = playerPtr->idlingRSpritePaths[0];
playerPtr->t2Path = playerPtr->idlingRSpritePaths[1];
playerPtr->t3Path = playerPtr->idlingRSpritePaths[2];
playerPtr->t4Path = playerPtr->idlingRSpritePaths[3];
playerPtr->t5Path = playerPtr->idlingRSpritePaths[4];
```

Thanks greatly if anyone does attempt to answer this.

Comment: Do they have the same size?

Comment: @songyuanyao thanks, yes they do. I have manyy other pass by refererce fuctions as you would expect in the program, and without problem.

Comment: Are you expecting t1Path, t2Path etc... to update when you assign to texturePaths[i]?

Comment: @S_BISHOP Then it looks fine. What do you mean "doesn't work"? Provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks everyone, may have been a mistake posting this, the goal was hopefully to learn something new about passing vectors by reference I may have not already understood, but the example is much to trivial.

Comment: Passing a vector by reference is the same as any other variable, and there's nothing wrong with the shown code. I'm sorry but we can't help to fix code we can't see :c

Comment: Not directly related, but rather than creating 5 `sf::Texture`, copying them into the `std::vector` and then destroying them again, you could just construct your `std::vector` with an initial size of 5: `std::vector sf::Textures textures(5);`